# How to create custom layout for seekbar in android?

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to develop custom layout for seekbar below shown.
I have  track,thumb and progress images .  Can any body help me?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35308311/2826147

Answer (score 0):

**XML code**

```
 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumbler_small"
    android:indeterminate="false" />
```

**seek_bar.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/SecondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/first"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/second"/>
</layer-list>
```

**first drawable is empty or shown not color full area.**

**second drawable is fill or color full area.**

[this](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-use-and-custom-seekbar-in-android.html) link help your more.

Comment: sir I am getting error `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@+android:id/
 SecondaryProgress').`