# Android Seek bar with specified hint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-seekbar

I am new to android 
Please any one help.how to change Seek bar hint.I have four types of food in seek bar.When I change the Seek bar to one food item.I need to show a hit message that related food item.

[image]

Comment: try to toast your choice..

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar

Comment: Is that an existing Android widget you're showing in that image?

Comment: Hi Doug ,I need to create that hint shape pragmatically and when we change the seek bar the seek bar hint and value should be chage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [discreteSeekBar](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar) ,

**Dependencies**

It uses `com.android.support:support-v4` as the only **dependency**.

**Usage**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use these **libraries** for android tooltip. Follow these link.
https://github.com/xizzhu/simple-tool-tip
  https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip

Comment: Thanks Sharjeel for your reply.