# Custom layout or design for seekbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

Is there a way to customize the look of the seek bar, so that I can put my own design/image for the seekbar (thumb, track and progress). I have looked at this post, but the link is broken.

[How to create custom layout for seekbar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227559/how-to-create-custom-layout-for-seekbar-in-android)

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35308311/2826147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help [custom seekbar](https://github.com/GuilhE/android-nickaknudson), you can change what you want (thumb, track and progress, and more usefull stuff) but only programmatically. I've contributed to this lib, the only catch is that this seekbar it's a range seekbar, but you can fork this repo and add the feature to enable range or not and remove one of the thumbs.

The quickest way to achieve that is to comment line 498 from `RangeSeekBar.java` (but you'll only affect the "visibility" the thumb still reacts to drag, you have to code a bit more ^^)

```
// draw minimum thumb
drawThumb(normalizedToScreen(mNormalizedMinValue), Thumb.MIN.equals(mPressedThumb), canvas);
```

and then inside your `Activity` you'll be using the `maxValue`:

```
mSeekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
        ...
        }
    });
```

Here's an example on how to customize your seekBar:

```
mSeekBar.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);
mSeekBar.setThumbImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.seek_thumb_normal));
mSeekBar.setProgressBackgroundColor(0xFF, 0xDD, 0xDD, 0xDD);
mSeekBar.setProgressLineColor(0xFF, 0xE8, 0x4E, 0x44);
mSeekBar.setMaxHeight(Utils.convertDpToPx(getActivity(), 2));
```

[image]
[image]

Or you use Android layout configurations:

```
<SeekBar
          ...
          android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_default_progress"
          android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb"/>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@color/some_color"/>
</item>
```

Comment: So the only way is to use these Github sources? There is no way to change it by default in Android?