# Android custom horizontal number picker with range selector

Tags: android, seekbar

I am new to android development.My requirement is to implement a number picker with range selector and the range values will be static as per the image.Is there any libraries or any other ways available to do this.I have researched a lot but cant get any thing related to this.

[image]

The section with green color can be scrolled to any where over the blue bar.And also the blue bar is scrollable itself having ranges from -40 to +40.

Please help

Comment: check [this](http://androidarena.co.in/awesome-custome-range-bar-with-a-photoshop-like-color-picker/) for starting step

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35308311/2826147

Answer (score 0):

May be it can solve you problem
https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar